# Price not updating in cart when the store is switched to another magento

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, custom-options, multistore

We have magento1.9 installed. In this site we have products with multiple options. We have added custom price for the options and it works fine. The product with the custom options and a total price can be added to the cart. The custom price is set using the code

```
$quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($new_price['price'])
```

My magento is multi language store with different currencies. The base price is in GBP. When we switch it to a different store the cart currency is updated but the price remains the same, it does not decrease or increase respectively with respect to the store currency.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a currency rate the prices not increase or decrease.

To set currency rate go to: “System->Manage Currency Rates” and make the conversions about your currencies.

Check this [guide](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#configuration/currency-setup.html)

Comment: But i have set the currency rate.This problem is only for the custom price.No issue for the default prices in cart for the product.